# Desktop Fails with "Oh no! Something has gone wrong."

Tags: debian, gnome3

The machine was running Debian wheezy and was recently upgraded to Jessie. Everything has worked fine for some time. However, after a reboot today the desktop won't load.

/var/log/messages shows gnome-shell: segfault at 0 error 4 in libupower-glib.so.3.0.0

I have tried reinstalling gnome-session, gdm3, libupower.

(Sorry about the formatting, I'm on a phone.)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. [Report it](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)? (As a temporary workaround, try a plain [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager) like [twm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm).)

Comment: I did file a bug on this and recent updates seem to have fixed the problem (things that rely on libupower are working again) though i'm not sure if my bug report mattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may probably a bug, you should report it...and the solution.. Temporary install another desktop and waiting for reply, if you have ability, compile it yourself.
PS: first you can find your system installed glib version, then compile **the same version** of glib replace stock one, have a try...